# Using same user control multiple times in same page with grid view functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I am using a user control to display a grid view and the grid contains it own methods.

I have id'd the grid as `gvPastInvestment`.

My problem is that when I use the control twice in the same page, the grid id's are duplicating and the grid function are not separate to both user controls.

Is there a way I can id the grid so it will be unique each time I duplicate the user control, and should be able to control its functions separately.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPastInvestment" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
     DataKeyNames="ID,InvestmentCategory,ContractorCategory,Year" ShowFooter="True"
     OnRowEditing="gvPastInvestment_RowEditing" 
     OnRowCancelingEdit="gvPastInvestment_RowCancelingEdit" 
     OnRowUpdating="gvPastInvestment_RowUpdating"
     OnRowDeleting="gvPastInvestment_RowDeleting" 
     OnRowCommand="gvPastInvestment_RowCommand"
     CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AllowSorting="true">
     <Columns>
         ....
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPastInvestment" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: And why don't you simply make the id and the methods unique in the markup and refactor each method to only contain the code that is unique for the specific grid? Expand your example markup here with 2 grids and your code behind and indicate what the issue is you try to address.

Comment: How do i make the id and methods unique . That's my problem

Comment: How about `gvPastInvestment001`, `gvPastInvestment002` etc?

Comment: i have the grid inside a user control, so is there a way to change the  id while i duplicate the user control.  `<uc1:grdContractInvestmentPlan runat="server" id="grdPastInvestmentPlan" type="P"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user control will handle the Id's,
It would create unique id's so it can identify itself.

It was not handling previously because `AllowSorting="true"` 
attribute was not added to the grid,
once i added that , User Control Did what needs to be done.

Answer (score -1):

Coming from a .NET background a long time ago in school, and knowing there are some limits, and not knowing exactly how everything is broken down here as far as how open Core is, or what newer versions of .NET will allow since they're trying to make them more like open sourced languaged and framework-friendly like their Node.js pkg in Code, used that, that was okay. I have a theory but how are you feeding your data, AJAX to an /api/ or outside pub api, EF, and is it XML or JSON?

I guess you're using Async, pardon my process, it's been a while, I was using straight SQL with IIS and EF back when I learned C#, anything remote to Async were doing jQuery's .ajax calls, right? It's been a while. Anyway, I'm not the word to absolutely trust I will admit, but coming from more of an angular and ES5-'7' background,

Mainly my thoughts:
I would figure out a way to create my own prop that you could template based on id, have a js logic, inside a self-invoking fn with something like.

```
var randomness = use a salt or a generator here 
var salted = salt algorithm + something else for added security.
var randoIdNumber = randomness + salted * 95834959834;
```

(or however complex or easy you want to make a script that changes randomly encrypted or decrypted etc.), then add that within the same scope out of the global namespace make a http post to a list.json or /api/genNumbers created for your prev used IDs to check against. ** keep in mind Also, you'd have to clean these bits of an idea mashed together a bit, and think possible garbage collection or efficiency by just replacing the previous var or keeping it and adding in a 'let' to stop the list from growing  on the list, if you're enterprise level and proj is large. <-- keep in mind I type this bit after below, sorry for the mess it's like 4am here.

OR just make a JS class with all this. and make some sort of list and checklist or JS array kv in the scope that you can then bring into play.  in your ASP.NET given

```
id= "{ randomId.id }"
```

or as an angular `class ng-class="ref to logic or just make it ugly and do it here var randomGvId = random generator "` could have a templated value that's async'd and randomized(anyhow, or anyway, above are just some roughly jotted thoughts to what I was thinking) and THEN

add the latest soon to be a "random" id to a list of previous id's/ prev generated or presented numbers so it ensures that it doesn't roll through the same combination or just use a different naming convention, you can make sure that the logic checks to see if the 'id' has been assigned before or is being used similarly to how you can do these types of things with angular and javascript. I would think in that direction. I will go back and brush up on my .NET, it's been since 4.5 came out, got cert'd but went into the js framework world of directives and injection, which i'm sure is pretty standard in .NET now. If you're curious as to what I mean let me know, and I'll put out some code for you. This is a rough rough 'answer', it's more of a suggestive idea for your thought process. If you don't have any clue how to go about it, I'd be happy to help brainstorm it and go back and find an instance in my code of something similar I've done in a project that may give you a better idea. Idk if .NET completely disallows this or not. But it's partially open sourced now. I bet I could find you something to run in your stack. Do you use angular or angular 2, KO, backbone or any of the major JS - MV*/MVC frameworks?

```
"{ scriptData.randomid }" or randid=" " in props/attributes
```

Warning, someone will answer this better for you, but trying to give you some ideas that I use in my world which hasn't been .NET for a while:

this is a somewhat half baked thought, cause you would have to also make sure that it wouldn't just be adding more GV's since new id's showup, even though you can change id names editing in VS but they just have to be unique, anytime you want.. I dont know if MS has a different idea when it's live and how it renders at runtime. maybe just  Maybe see what it renders first to at runtime if theres a templated number or research whether you can add your own property/attribute cause that would erase the first million lines I wrote and forget it, it's in the bag with a few lines of code then use the idea,

`<asp:WHATEVER ID="{ templatedRandoNumIdorGuid }" or leave id="" the same thing or blank if you can, and add like name="{ randomValue }" myRandomId="{ randomValue }" ng-class or ng-model or ng-bind ="{ randomValue }"`

Haha, I warned you it's half baked but it would be a good way to go about it IF you can have custom props/attributes or make id= value be an injected generated value. This above is NOT the best way to go about it. I already see some things that shouldn't ever be said lol but may help you catch the idea of what I'm trying to get across.